# What network layer handles responding to pings?

Tags: networking, ping, icmp

I've been learning about TCP and UDP lately, and I know that `ping` uses ICMP so I'm trying to understand that too. My understanding is that when the command `ping google.com` is run, your computer sends an echo request ICMP packet over IP to google, and then google responds with an echo reply message.

My question is, when a server responds with that echo reply message, what is actually taking care of that? Is it the operating system? Is it a particular application? Or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the Kernel module which responds the ICMP requests. The ICMPv4 module is [net/ipv4/icmp.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/icmp.c).

The ICMP module defines a table of array on how to handle various ICMP requests with object being `icmp_objects`, named `icmp_pointers` which is indexed by ICMP message type.

ICMP control structure:

```
struct icmp_control {
  void (*handler)(struct sk_buff *skb);
  short error; /* This ICMP is classed as an error message */
};

static const struct icmp_control icmp_pointers[NR_ICMP_TYPES + 1] = {
...
  [ICMP_ECHO] = {
        .handler = icmp_echo,
  },
...
};
```

From above struct, when you send a echo request to google.com server the message type will be `icmp_echo` boiling down to subroutine call [icmp_echo()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/icmp.c#L878) which handles echo (ping) requests (ICMP_ECHO) by sending echo replies (ICMP_ECHOREPLY) with
[icmp_reply()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/icmp.c#L387).

Answer (score -1):

In terms of the TCP/IP reference model it is the Network layer of the protocol stack, which is normally in the kernel.